# Hide pages from navigation in site definition

Tags: top-link-bar

I have a site definition created from team site, and I activated publishing feature on this site, the pages appear on left and top navigation once I create the site. I have feature receivers on the site that create my navigation dynamic.

I tried to remove `<nav>` from the site definition but that broke the navigation. how do I remove unnecessary pages that I added in my features from navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have activated publishing feature on your site, you can include this code in your feature reciever that creates the navigation:

```
              //get reference to the publishing web, store it in publishingWeb
              //This is how to do it for quick launch                   
              publishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;

              //This is how to do it for top navigation
              publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;
```